# Which poem about a soldier does Honor Harrington epitomize?

Tags: honorverse, poetry

I seem to recall that there is a poem referenced in one of the later Honor Harrington books.  It is about a soldier, and the poem basically describes Honor to a tee.  I looked the poem up years ago and seem to remember it went something like this:

> A soldier is...
> a soldier does...
> a soldier would...

Something like that.  I hope someone can help me and tell me what it is called and maybe who wrote it.

Comment: David Weber wrote "If  any  single  poem  sums  up  Honor  Harrington’s  entire  life,  it  would undoubtedly  be  Rudyard  Kipling’s  “If.”" Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes yes. That is it. Thank you. I wanted to share it with a friend of mine. Thank you.

Comment: @KyleTaylor Glad to help Kyle. Can you click the green checkmark to let people know that the question has been answered? Thanks!

Comment: The answer to just about any question regarding poetry and soldiers is "Rudyard Kipling".

Answer (score 18):

David Weber made this remark in the afterword of "[Uncompromising Honor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?679539)":

> If any single poem sums up Honor  Harrington’s  entire  life,
> it  would undoubtedly  be  Rudyard  Kipling’s  “If.”

The first verse of the Rudyard Kipling poem "[If —](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46473/if---)" is:

> If you can keep your head when all about you
>
> Are losing theirs and blaming it on you,
>
> If you can trust yourself when all men doubt you,
>
> But make allowance for their doubting too;
>
> If you can wait and not be tired by waiting,
>
> Or being lied about, don’t deal in lies,
>
> Or being hated, don’t give way to hating,
>
> And yet don’t look too good, nor talk too wise:

finishing with the somewhat inappropriate (for Honor Harrington):

> you’ll be a Man, my son!